# How to connect mongodb instance region wise from my node js application server

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, architecture

I have one master instance of mongo db and 3 read only instances configured on different regions. Now whenever a request lands on to my node js application server, i want to connect to near by db instance to get data.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** ( better, since you dont care where the application is , the driver find the nearest members automatically)
To achieve this behaviour you need to set the read-preference to  [nearest](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-nearest).
That way your driver will route your read request to much closest member depending on periodical latency check.

**Option 2:**
You define custom [tags](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#mongodb-rsconf-rsconf.members-n-.tags) for members known in advance are in the application region and use those tags when read request are sent.